# How to add a button to iOS text selection action control

Tags: ios, text, controls, selection, share

Does anybody know how I can add a button like the "Share" button in the example to that kind of control. I have a UIWebView where I want to offer the user with special actions to take after she selects text in it.

[Example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/did5N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is an instance of `UIMenuController`. You can add your own items to the `menuItems` property and implement `canPerformAction:withSender:` to determine if the item is appropriate to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIMenuItem *item = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Title"
                                               action: @selector(methodToFire:)] ;
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems: [NSArray arrayWithObject: item]];
```